# ASP .Net MVC Filepond get file unique Id in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was reading Filepond's documentation [enter link description here](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/)

They have basic steps I should follow for dealing with file uploads.  I've tackled 1-4 (hopefully correct)

[image]

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form-w", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReturnUrl)
    <input type="file"
           class="filepond"
           name="filepond"
           multiple
           data-max-file-size="3MB"
           data-max-files="3">
    <div class="form-label-group">
            <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Your First Name", @type = "text", @id = "inputFirstName", required = "required" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-label-group">
            <label for="inputLastName">Last Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Your Last Name", @type = "text", @id = "inputLastName", required = "required" })
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block wd-btn-round-2 text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-2 btn-outline-black bg-color-yellow" type="submit">Register</button>
}
```

My question is how do I submit the hidden files with the post method?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)            
{
    .... code for registering
}
```

RegisterViewModel.cs

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Now my question is what do I add to RegisterViewModel so that it picks up the hidden input fields (can be multiple).

[image]

Comment: BTW, when using `TextBoxFor` you don't need to specify `@type = "text"`. You can also omit `@id` as `TextBoxFor` will generate one for you, which you can reference by using `Html.IdFor<>( expr )`.

Comment: FilePond has an example backend for PHP here: https://github.com/pqina/filepond-boilerplate-php - perhaps you can derive from that?

Comment: @Dai I had a look at it but I'm not that well verse in PHP. My main question is how do I submit all the hidden inputs with the name filepond to my post method. I tried adding the property `public ICollection<string> Filepond {get; set;}` but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a simple solution using a hidden text field.

Add following to your form

HTML Field

```
<input id="FileIDs" type="hidden" asp-for="FileIDs" />
```

Model Property

```
[BindProperty]
public string FileIDs { get; set; }
```

Filepond onload event

```
pond.setOptions({
    server: {
        process: {
            method: 'POST',
            onload: (response) => {
                var val = $("#FileIDs").val();
                (val == '') ? $("#FileIDs").val(response) : $("#FileIDs").val(val + "," + response);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

After upload the **ids** would be placed in the text field **FileIDs**

```
<input id="FileIDs" type="hidden" name="FileIDs" value="id1,id2,...">
```

Of course, you server should return the ids after successful upload.

After form submit you will have the ids in the **FileIDs** property of your model.
You will just need to split them to a text list.

```
var list = FileIDs.Split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Tolbxela is not wrong, but I just found a way to do it better

On your `RegisterViewModel.cs` add this line

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromForm(Name = "filepond")]  //'filepond' is the input name from your view 
public List<string> ListFilesId { get; set; }
```

That's it, now you can get all your file Id's from your ViewModel